# GitHub API. Как получить количество публичных репозиториев в search запросе?

Tags: javascript, github-api

Делаю приложение Github search, оно имеет поле ввода, по введённым символам должен происходить поиск и вывод инфы - `name, avatar и public_repos.`
Запрос на поиск пользователя делаю на `https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${searchValue}`,
в ответе есть разная инфа, но нет инфы о `public_repos` - количестве репозиториев, эта инфа содержится по другому эндпоинту, `https://api.github.com/users/${userLogin}` , т.е `userLogin`  - это конкретный пользователь. У меня получается следующая картина, я делаю запрос на `search`, получаю в ответе массив из 30 объектов, вытягиваю у них `login`, и делаю еще 30 запросов на `users`. Github ограничивает количество запросов 60 в час, несколько таких запросов и мой ip в блоке.
Вопрос: есть ли возможность получить нужную мне инфу путем дополнительных настроек строки запроса или может быть есть вариант как снять ограничения на количество запросов? Либо может есть у кого идеи как решить мою проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если верить [документации](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#requests-from-personal-accounts), то вам просто надо зарегаться в системе и тогда сможете выполнять до 15,000 запросов в час